# UI-Select reset-search-input does not work

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Please see my code below, when a choice is select from an input by typing something in i.e "Fr" and all the countries starting with France would appear, however after the input is selected the input field does not get cleared

```
 <ui-select multiple
                       ng-model="quote.targetLanguage"
                       reset-search-input="true"
                       theme="bootstrap"
                       ng-disabled="disabled"
                       close-on-select="false"
                       style="width: 800px;">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">
                    {{$item.language}}
                </ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="lang in controllersData.languages | filter: $select.search">
                    <div ng-bind-html="lang.language | highlight: $select.search"></div>

                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
```

Comment: what version of ui-select are you using?

Comment: * Version: 0.9.8 - 2015-02-16T15:10:00.891Z

Comment: can you try with version 0.9.5 just to be curious thats the one i currently use that clearing search works there. so if after you change the version still doesn't clear the search there must be something else wrong, but lets clear the version issue first

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: is your model updated properly?

Comment: yes. It is as far as I can tell.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: i just went through the source code, it seems that if multiple is used reset-search-input is ignored, for some reason, so my advice would be use the on-select function to clear the search field of the $select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it at the global level using the uiSelectConfig constant like:

```
app.config(function(uiSelectConfig) {
  uiSelectConfig.resetSearchInput = true;
});
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is still occurring in version 0.11.2.

As Dayan suggested in the comments, resetting the search in the `on-select` event solves it:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="numbers" on-select="numberSelected($select)">
...
</ui-select>
```

Then in your controller/directive:

```
scope.numberSelected = function ($select) {
    // clear search text
    $select.search = '';
};
```