# ui-select clearing input after selection

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ui-select2, ui-select

Is there something that would allow the typed input to be cleared after a displayed option is selected? Currently, the user has to erase what they typed and type something new in and I want it to be erased after they select something. This is what I currently have.

```
            <ui-select multiple close-on-select="false" ng-model="vm.model.childUsers">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select...">{{$item.fullName}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="user.userProfileId as user in vm.availableUsers | filter: $select.search">{{user.fullName}}</ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
```

Comment: I have found reset-search-input but it is currently not working.

Comment: OK, solved it. You can't use reset-search-input and use multiple. This helped me out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573688/ui-select-reset-search-input-does-not-work